# PHP: One item with class="active" in navbar created with foreach-loop

Tags: php

I have an array with my navbar items

pagearray.php :

```
<?php
$pages = array(
        array(
        "slug" => "/php/site1.php",
        "title" => 'Site One',
    ),
        array(
        "slug" => "/php/site2.php",
        "title" => 'Site Two',
    ),
        array(
        "slug" => "/php/site2.php",
        "title" => 'Site Three',
    ),
)
?>
```

And im trying to build a navigation bar using foreach-loop, where the page you are on would have .active class.

navbar.php

```
<?php 
include "/includes/pagearray.php";

    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        echo "<li><a href=\"$page[slug]\">$page[title] </a></li>";
    }
?>
```

Is this even possible by using only HTML, CSS and PHP? Am I using wrong technique to build a navbar?

Comment: change `"<li><a href=\"$page[slug]\">$page[title] </a></li>"` to `'<li><a href="'.$page[slug].'">$page["title"].' </a></li>'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your new navbar.php - this should work. This will add `active` class to the links (`<a>` elements)

```
<?php
include "/includes/pagearray.php";

foreach ($pages as $page) {
    echo '<li><a href="' . $page['slug'] . '" class="' . ((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $page['slug'])) ? "active" : "") . '">' . $page['title'] . '</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: I can see it should work, but for some reason it doesn't. I echoed the ```$page['slug']``` and ```$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']```, and they are giving the right values, but for some reason, it doesn't add the "active"-part, every ```<a>``` element has emply class in them. Thanks for help already anyway, I learned a lot from this.

Comment: Ok, so instead of using ```strpos``` I used ```($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == $page['slug']  ? "active" : "")``` and it works like a charm!